# Using MinGW - Initgraph() does not compile

Tags: c++, bgi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winbgim.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <graphics.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gdriver = 9;
    int gmode = 2;
    initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode, "");
    setbkcolor(WHITE);
    setcolor(BLACK);
    cleardevice();
    circle(320,240,180);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error -

> ..\src\LoveGraphics.cpp:18:33: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string >
>     constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>       initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode, "");

Comment: Where did you get `graphics.h` from? That's a very old library. You should use something more modern like opengl.

Comment: As for the error message, literal strings in C++ (like e.g. `""`) are really arrays of *constant* characters. As other arrays, they decay to pointers to their first element, and that pointer is of the type `const char*`. This is very different type from the `char*` that the `initgraph` apparently expects. The only solution (if you want to continue using this *very* old and outdated library) is to create your own non-constant array.

Comment: The error message helpfully tells you which compile option you want to change.  Use -Wwrite-strings-

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the empty string to initgraph() the BGI file containing your driver must be in the current directory.

Regarding the C++ error you could try

```
string dummy = "";

initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode, dummy);
```

It might work. However I agree with the comments, this is a very old library. Why not install linux on [a partition of] the machine and learn to use gdk or Cairo?

Comment: Hi Jon Guiton,

I tried "string dummy", and it does not work.

Comment: now, additionally, with the earlier error, i also get few more errors..

undefined reference to `initgraph'

any help please.

Comment: It sounds like the compiler is not finding the header files and/or libraries.

Comment: All - 

After hours and hours of research on the google, i conclude that using GRAPHICS.H for my crave for doing graphics performing is making ZERO SENSE.

basis all your advises, I have now downloaded OpenGL and IDE as DEV-C++.. but seems, am still struggling in graphics programming using C++...

any good solution from the techies there will surely help.

Thanks, Mukesh